# Integrate function with parameter

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

I would like to evaluate for $y>0$

$$I(y):=\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1 + x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}(ax^2 + 1)} dx$$ where $a \in (0,1).$

Mathematica even has a closed expression for this, but this one does not work for $a \in (0,1)$ but only for $a>1.$

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: try $$x=\tan(t)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time I see something this, I think: let $u=x/\sqrt{1+x^2}$!

Following that, you will end up with
$$
\int\frac{u^2}{1-(1-a)u^2}\,du,
$$
which you easily can calculate using polynomial division. You will end up with something like (when going back to $x$),
$$
\int\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}(1+ax^2)}\,dx=-\frac{x}{(1-a)\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\frac{1}{(1-a)^{3/2}}\,\text{artanh}\,\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{1-a}x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\Bigr)+C.
$$
I think you can use this primitive for $0<a<1$, so just insert limits.